# Eclipse Luna does not show javascript files at project explorer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

At Eclipse Luna I added 'js' folder to 'JavaScript resources', made this folder as source in properties and put inside .js file

Why Eclipse does not show it under 'JavaScript resources' at my source? There is empty

[image]

Do I forgot to make something?